# Trying to print directory system tree from scratch in Python (no imported modules)

Tags: python, directory, tree, filesystems

So I am making a basic directory system in python from scratch. I am pretty new to coding and am doing python as a Uni module. So I have made the functions for creating the tree from scratch, but now I have been tasked with actually just printing out the object as it is (not visually to see each step of the directory tree).
So this is my code currently

```
class File:
    pass

class Directory(File):
    def __init__(self, name, left=None, right=None):
        self.name = name
        self.left = left
        self.right = right
        
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"{self.name}, {self.left}, {self.right}"
        

class PlainFile(File):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

When I try to print root, I want to essentially see the whole thing.
But it gives me the <main.blahblah when printing the names of the classes and other parts too. I think my def__repr__ needs to be recursive in nature but for the life of me I have no clue how to do it:( Please help!

Comment: Unrelated to your direct question, but it seems like none of your directories have a `right` node since you've assigned a list to the `left`. Not sure if that's intended, but it seems a bit strange.

Comment: They do have right nodes unless they are a PlainFile (which is a leaf node). However Issac directory only has one node. Please see updated question for image of tree.

Comment: If you print `root.right`, you will get `None`. This is because the directory called `"home"` is the second entry in the list stored in `root.left`.

Comment: Ah okay, how would I change this?

Comment: Get rid of the brackets `[]` that make it a list.

Comment: I thought of something else that has simplified it all massively. Instead of using self.right and self.left I have just defined self.List_of_contents. What do you think of this?

Comment: that seems reasonable

Comment: I did it and it worked perfectly! Thank you for all the help it means a lot! Now I want to print it out so that it shows the directory system with each directory and it's sub directories using indentation to show it's depth in the system. How would I go about this?

Comment: That probably belongs in a different question from this one.

Comment: You're right. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

If you make your `PlainFile` class implement `__repr__(self)` instead of `__str__(self)`, it should work. See [What is the difference between __str__ and __repr__?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436703/what-is-the-difference-between-str-and-repr) for more details. The good thing about your `Directory` class's `__repr__` is that it's *already* recursive, since it would call the inner `File`'s `__repr__` functions when evaluating the f-string.

**Edit:** Adding a full solution to match the expected output.

```py
class File:
    pass

class Directory(File):
    def __init__(self, name, left=None, right=None):
        self.name = name
        self.left = left
        self.right = right

    def __repr__(self):
        arg_str = ", ".join(
            str(arg)
            for arg in (self.name, self.left, self.right)
            if arg is not None
        )
        return f"Directory({arg_str})"


class PlainFile(File):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"PlainFile({self.name})"
```

I use `str()` in the `Directory` implementation because it doesn't add quotes to the `self.name` since it's a string. By default, `__str__` is implemented as `__repr__`, so it would also work on the `File` objects in `left` or `right`, and calling `str()` on a list will make it call `repr()` on its items.

Comment: Thank you very much, okay so I did that and now it prints most of everything. However It prints 'none' where there is not a branch. To get rid of this none and make it exactly like the picture I linked, would I just include an if statement somewhere saying if = none print "" ? Also, the other thing I want is for it to also print where the class names have been called. In the picture I linked, it includes the whole object as originally written, including where it says Directory or PlainFile for example. How would I achieve this?

Comment: Yep you would need some if statements checking if the `left` or `right` are `None` when constructing your string. You can get the name of the class using `type(self).__name__`, or you could just hardcode it.

Comment: @BanAckerman I updated the answer with a full solution.